# PHP Storing sessions

Tags: performance, session, storage, php

Which way would be the most effective way of storing a session in php (for login or user-related data)?

Would the best thing be a database or using the built in $_SESSION in php?
which one would be the most effective when it comes to a larger website and speed in general?

Comment: Make sure you know what you want to achieve. Usually $_SESSION is used for session data (eg. user id) and database for intrasession data (eg. user preferences).

Comment: Here: https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20store%20sessions%20in%20php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp - that ought to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very bad question because its not defining a single answer but ill go ahead and try to suit your needs

first there will be a checking so if username doesnt equal one on the data base
or the email and do propper error checking once you can check for usernames in the database and are succesfully creating functions for that

you need to have a user login ,,if credentials were truthfull then

```
 session_start();

    function logged_in()
    {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
    }





if ($login === false)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Wrong username/password combination';
        } else 
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
```

try this series is highly recomended

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kyQGBABA38&list=PLE134D877783367C7  youll be done watching it in two days but will have a good foundation on this issue

i hope i helped

Comment: which i didnt left out? lol i know just trying to paint a picture

Comment: If you're going to **"paint a picture"**, you better make sure there's a proper **"canvas/frame"** to put it into. Otherwise, it's not **"good practice"**. I'll give you a clue: `session...`.

Comment: **DING! DING! DING!** We have **.::WINNER::.** folks! @mpm ;-)

Comment: hahaha there sorry i expected @squirreldev to have a clue about starting a session before setting it or destroying it

Comment: @GunrJesra This could be of help to others who may not know about sessions. ;-) You can't assume, and as the 'ol saying goes **"If you assume, that could make an ASS out of U and ME"** (*Or something like that, LOL*), cheers mate!

Comment: My question is not about how i make a session in php. It's a question about how to store the session. CI used to only support database storage in their past versions but they have now gone over to a more broad coverage of sessions. But over to the point. I'm trying to figgure out if it's faster and safer to make a mirror to php's session functions and store them in a mysql database.
I'm pretty sure my question did not ask for a way to make a login system nor a way to make a php session. On the other side, thank you for taking the time to look at the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to believe the built-in PHP mechanism is slow or bad. It is writing to files, which is perfect for single-server scenarios that about 90% of websites make use of, it is thoroughly tested and works. The inner workings do use compiled C language for the best possible performance with this storage.

Whatever you do yourself must either be implemented in PHP, which is slower, or you have to get into the business of creating PHP Session Save Handlers in C.

So if you really get into having a multi-server setup with a loadbalancer in front, and no stickyness configured, only then do you need a session storage that is accessible from all the webservers. There are plenty of solutions already existing:

Memcached - when the memcached extension is installed, there is also the [memcached session save handler](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php).

You can also try the Zend Session Cluster that comes with Zend Server.

And you can try to code your own session handler, but you must make sure that you do proper locking! Otherwise concurrent requests will overwrite each others session data. That is where most code I have seen so far fails, even mature frameworks like [Symfony 2 still do with non-native storage](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4976).

PHP takes care of locking itself only if the internal session save handler is used (and coded correctly), so effectively only one script can run per session id. All others are stopped at the call to `session_start()`.

If you think that none of the existing save handlers will fit your requirements, then you have to implement something yourself, but your question does not sound like you are already accustomed to clustered webserver environments.

Regarding "What is most effective"? Effective or efficient? Or performant? Or fastest? Nobody will know if you cannot name the numbers to measure! And how to measure.

And even if that would be known, there simply is no way of knowing beforehand. Just think about someone saying "Use a database, this is always faster", and then you end up with a bad provider in a shared hosting system with an overloaded database system that delivers absolutely no performance, and you are like "no way is this database any faster than files" - and you are right. For the same reason, saying than NOT using databases is faster is a lie also.

Measure The Performance! Change something and see if it is faster. If it is, stay there, and go back otherwise.